# Datetime differences on python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have  DateTime, from string I convert them on IS0 format example. `ISODate("2016-06-24T09:07:31.097Z")`

I want to find the differences between them using python, so I did this:

```
string_older = "2016-05-18T20:53:43.776456"
string_young = "2016-05-16T20:53:43.776456"
datetime_older = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_older, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f") //date on ISO format
datetime_young = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_young, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f") //date on ISO format
a = time.mktime(datetime_older)
b = time.mktime(datetime_young)
diff = a - b
seconds = int(diff) % 60
```

But this gives this error `TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not datetime.datetime` 
at this line `time.mktime(datetime_older)`.
I don't know how to fix it? Please help.

Comment: I don't understand why you are calling `time.mktime` at all. You have datetimes already, you can subtract them from each other.

Comment: I thought to convert it to time and then subtract for find difference on seconds, I didn't know that I can subtract dates directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtracting both `datetime`s gives you a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects). To get the difference expressed in seconds, call its [`total_seconds`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) method.

```
string_older = "2016-05-18T20:53:43.776456"
string_young = "2016-05-16T20:53:43.776456"
datetime_older = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_older, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f") //date on ISO format
datetime_young = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_young, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")

timedelta = datetime_older - datetime_young
seconds = timedelta.total_seconds()
```

> timedelta.**total_seconds()**
>
> Return the total number of seconds contained in the duration. Equivalent to (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6 computed with true division enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this; there is no need to use time.mktime() as you already have datetimes.

```
import time, datetime
string_older = "2016-05-18T20:53:43.776456"
string_young = "2016-05-16T20:53:43.776456"

datetime_older = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_older, "%Y-%m-  %dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
datetime_young = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_young, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")

c = datetime_older - datetime_young
print(divmod(c.days * 86400 + c.seconds, 60) ) # minutes, seconds
```

Comment: Why not use total_seconds? (See my answer)

Comment: we can use total_seconds. This is just an another way of doing the same thing.